# Connectycube Flutter IOS CallKit unable to accept call when phone is locked

Tags: iphone, flutter, voip, callkit, connectycube

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open app
2. lock phone
3. receive incoming call
4. swipe to answer call
5. call kit shows in progress call and call is not established

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: the Connectycube team knows about this issue and works on it, the fix will be provided in a few days.